# How do I retrieve URLs and data from the URLs from a list of weblinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

"Hello, i am quite new to web-scraping. I recently retrieved a list of web-links and there are URLs within these links containing data from tables. I am planning to scrape the data but can't seem to even get the URLs. Any form of help is much appreciated"

"The list of weblinks are

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1920

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1921

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1922

https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=2019"

"From the list of links, i am planning to

a. get the URLs within these links

https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19190802-0

https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19190811-0

https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19200223-0"

"b. get data from tables within each URL
(e.g., Incident date, incident time, type, operator, registration, msn, first flight, classification)"

```
    #Get the list of weblinks

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    headers = {'insert user agent'}

    #start of code

    mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/"
    def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
       result = requests.get(mainurl)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
       datatable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
       return datatable

    datatable = getAndParseURL(mainurl)

    #go through the content and grab the URLs

    links = []
    for link in datatable:
        if 'Year' in link['href']:
            url = link['href']
            links.append(mainurl + url)

    #check if links are in dataframe

    df = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['url'])

    df.head(10)

    #save the links to a csv

    df.to_csv('aviationsafetyyearlinks.csv')


    #from the csv read each web-link and get URLs within each link

    import csv
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    contents = []
    df = pd.read_csv('aviationsafetyyearlinks.csv')

    urls = df['url']
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) 
        for url in contents:
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            addtable = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
```

"I am only able to get the list of web-links and am unable to get the URLs nor the data within these web-links. The code continually shows arrays
not really sure where my code is wrong, appreciate any help and many thanks in advance."

Answer (score 0):

While requesting the page.Add User Agent.

```
headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
mainurl = "https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919"
def getAndParseURL(mainurl):
    result = requests.get(mainurl,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
    datatable = soup.select('a[href*="database/record"]')
    return datatable

print(getAndParseURL(mainurl))
```

Comment: "Hello, this works! Am able to retrieve 2 of the urls. 
But i was wondering if it was possible to use a list of URLs instead of one URL in the mainurl?"

The list of URLs are from 1919 to 2019:
https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919
https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1920
https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1921
https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1922

i tried doing so but faced this error:
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0 https://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.ph...